# hbase 0.90.5 not work after replace hadoop*.jar in hbase/lib/

Tags: hadoop, hbase

i have Debian 6.03 and problem with best friends hbase and hadoop
step by step, I want working configuration hbase (standalone for the first step) and hadoop :

```
wget http://www.sai.msu.su/apache//hbase/hbase-0.90.5/hbase-0.90.5.tar.gz
tar xzfv hbase-0.90.5.tar.gz
sudo mv hbase-0.90.5 /usr/local/
sudo ln -s hbase-0.90.5/ hbase
sudo chown -R hduser:hadoop hbase*

lrwxrwxrwx  1 hduser hadoop   13 Янв 21 10:11 hbase -> hbase-0.90.5/
drwxr-xr-x  8 hduser hadoop 4096 Янв 21 10:11 hbase-0.90.5

dan@master:/usr/local/hbase$ su hduser
hduser@master:/usr/local/hbase$ bin/start-hbase.sh
starting master, logging to /usr/local/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-hduser-master-master.out
hduser@master:/usr/local/hbase$ bin/hbase shell
HBase Shell; enter 'help<RETURN>' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit<RETURN>" to leave the HBase Shell
Version 0.90.5, r1212209, Fri Dec  9 05:40:36 UTC 2011

hbase(main):001:0> list
TABLE                                                                                                            
0 row(s) in 0.8560 seconds
```

But, after unpack hadoop core v 1.0 in hbase lib/ folder - I got:

```
hduser@master:/usr/local/hbase$ bin/stop-hbase.sh
hduser@master:/usr/local/hbase$ cp ../hadoop/hadoop-core-1.0.0.jar lib/
hduser@master:/usr/local/hbase$ rm lib/hadoop-core-0.20-append-r1056497.jar
hduser@master:/usr/local/hbase$ bin/start-hbase.sh
starting master, logging to /usr/local/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-hduser-master-master.out

hduser@master:/usr/local/hbase$ bin/hbase shell
HBase Shell; enter 'help<RETURN>' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit<RETURN>" to leave the HBase Shell
Version 0.90.5, r1212209, Fri Dec  9 05:40:36 UTC 2011

hbase(main):001:0> list
TABLE                                                                                                            

ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ZooKeeperConnectionException: HBase is able to connect to ZooKeeper but the connection closes immediately. This could be a sign that the server has too many connections (30 is the default). Consider inspecting your ZK server logs for that error and then make sure you are reusing HBaseConfiguration as often as you can. See HTable's javadoc for more information.
```

Why I need zookeeper on standalone after replace hadoop-core*.jar?
how to fix it?

Comment: what does your zookeeper log says?

Comment: Your hbase is not able to communicate to hadoop. check your host file. if you have 127.0.1.1 the comment it and add your ip and some name to it and check

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured hbase-env.sh to manage Zookeeper itself?
Have you configured zookeeper quorums in hbase-site.xml?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and solved it by configuring yarn and map-reduce.
Try this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28877600/why-do-i-need-to-keep-hbase-lib-folder-in-hdfs/29121662#29121662).