# Why do I need to keep hbase/lib folder in hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have a main cluster which has some data in Hbase, and I want to replicate it. I've already created a backup cluster and created snapshot of the table I want to replicate. I am trying to export the snapshot from source cluster to destination, but I am getting some errors.
I am executing

```
./hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.ExportSnapshot -snapshot mySnap -copy-to hdfs://198.58.88.11:9000/hbase
```

and as a result of execution I got

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/vagrant/hbase/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/vagrant/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2015-03-05 10:58:43,155 INFO  [main] snapshot.ExportSnapshot: Copy Snapshot Manifest
2015-03-05 10:58:43,596 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
2015-03-05 10:58:43,597 INFO  [main] jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
2015-03-05 10:58:43,890 INFO  [main] mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area file:/home/vagrant/hadoop/hadoop-datastore/mapred/staging/vagrant1489762780/.staging/job_local1489762780_0001
2015-03-05 10:58:43,892 ERROR [main] snapshot.ExportSnapshot: Snapshot export failed
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://namenode:9000/home/vagrant/hbase/lib/hbase-client-1.0.0.jar
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1072)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1064)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1064)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestamps(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestampsAndCacheVisibilities(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1282)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1282)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.ExportSnapshot.runCopyJob(ExportSnapshot.java:775)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.ExportSnapshot.run(ExportSnapshot.java:934)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.ExportSnapshot.innerMain(ExportSnapshot.java:1008)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.ExportSnapshot.main(ExportSnapshot.java:1012)
```

So, as I understood, it tries to find `base-client-1.0.0.jar`
But is looking in `hdfs://namenode:9000/home/vagrant/hbase/lib/hbase-client-1.0.0.jar` and not in local storage.
Any ideas why it is happening?

Comment: Any answer? That would help me a lot.

Comment: @FabioMoreira, I have this issue while I was using Ubuntu 14.04, I used Ubuntu 12.04 and it worked. Changing OS was not a problem in my case, but if it is in your case, consider checking the version of hadoop jars in hbase and actual hadoop version are same. Make sure that your class path contains the path to this jars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the cause of the problem was misconfiguration of yarn and map-reduce. After configuring them correctly, I was able to export a snapshot without problems.

Make your `mapred-site.xml` to looks like this

```
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
      <value>yarn</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.address</name>
      <value>cluster2.master:8021</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

And `yarn-site.xml`

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
  <value>cluster2.master</value>
  <description>The hostname of the RM.</description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
  <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  <description>shuffle service that needs to be set for Map Reduce to run </description>
</property>
```

`cluster2.master` should be changed according to your settings.

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled upon this with HBase 1.0 and HDFS 2.6.0 from Cloudera 5.

The workaround that I used and which made it work is ..to actually copy those JARs into HDFS. I know that it's ugly, but it works so it's better that nothing.

Start with:

```
export CLUSTER_NAME=<your_hdfs_cluster_name>
```

..and then create the necessary dirs with:

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p hdfs://$CLUSTER_NAME/usr/lib/hbase/lib/
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p hdfs://$CLUSTER_NAME/usr/lib/zookeeper
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p hdfs://$CLUSTER_NAME/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p hdfs://$CLUSTER_NAME/usr/lib/hadoop
```

...and copy all the JARs with:

```
hdfs dfs -cp file:///usr/lib/hbase/lib/*.jar hdfs://$CLUSTER_NAME/usr/lib/hbase/lib/
hdfs dfs -cp file:///usr/lib/zookeeper/*.jar hdfs://$CLUSTER_NAME/usr/lib/zookeeper
hdfs dfs -cp file:///usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/*.jar hdfs://$CLUSTER_NAME/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce
hdfs dfs -cp file:///usr/lib/hadoop/*.jar hdfs://$CLUSTER_NAME/usr/lib/hadoop
```